# .load and .getScript not working after refresh

Tags: jquery, html

I am loading my nav bar into each page using the .load function and the getting the necessary script using the .getScript function, my issue is that after refreshing the page the script is not being added. Here is my code

```
<script>
  $(function(){
    $("#includeHere").load("nav.html");
  });  
  $.getScript("../js/bootstrap-hover-dropdown.min.js");
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that this worked for me

```
<script>$(function(){$("#includeHere").load("nav.html", $(function()      
{$.getScript("../js/bootstrap-hover-dropdown.min.js");}))});</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
  <script>
      $.getScript("../js/bootstrap-hover-dropdown.min.js", $(function(){
          $("#includeHere").load("nav.html");
        });
      );
  </script>
```